# Jquery Not working on a Page even after linking latest jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

Please check the following page.
http://legaleagleweb.com/views/Index.aspx

Jquery is not working . I have linked the latest jquery library but still i get error like 
**Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function**
And
**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

Please check it and tell me what is the issue.

Comment: Post code, not a link.

Comment: I have different jquery library linked to this page. Posting code will not help. I am getting error in different files. Please the open and then you can troubleshoot it in a better way.

Comment: That's not how this site works. This is one of the reasons questions get closed here (and why this question will be closed if you do not add code): Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is problematic

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        //my jquery 
        jQuery.noConflict();
    $(window).load(function (e) {
        jQuery("#bn1").breakingNews({
            effect: "slide-h",
            autoplay: true,
            timer: 2000,
            color: "darkred"
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

replace with this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#bn1").breakingNews({
            effect: "slide-h",
            autoplay: true,
            timer: 2000,
            color: "darkred"
        });
    });
</script>
```